# Pip, Python, and Visual Studio

Tags: python, visual-studio-2017

I am receiving a similar error message such as here:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23708898/pip-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command

However, my scripts are located here:

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python37_64\Scripts

The above path has been add to the PATH environment variable.

How to get pip working as expected?

Comment: What are the results of `where pip` and `where python`?

Comment: I see a discrepancy! Thanks. I will post more later.

Comment: Interestingly, pip is located:

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python37_64\Scripts

and python:

C:\Users\[username]\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37

Comment: Out of curiosity, does `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python37_64` (without the `Scripts` directory) contain a `python.exe`?

Comment: Yes sir

Which should be used. It appears easier to redirect Python than pip, no?

Answer (score 0):

It seems as if you have two installations of Python. Essentially, you should pick one and add `pip` (or `python`) to your path for that installation.

> Which should be used? It appears easier to redirect Python than `pip`, no?

You can choose to redirect Python if you wish. With that said, I am not certain I would choose the version in `Program Files (x86)`. That folder can cause issues with Python installations as it is treated specially by Windows.

My thought would be to consider using the version in
`C:\Users[username]\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37`.